# WndProc, Marshal.DestroyStructure & preventing memory leaks

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke, marshalling, wndproc

Just a general question, take the following code from a WindowsForms application:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x216)  // WM_MOVING = 0x216
    {
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle) Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof (Rectangle));
        DoSomethingWithRect(rect);
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Am I supposed to call Marshal.DestroyStructure(m.LParam) after DoSomethingWithRect in order to prevent a memory leak? I will be happy to get an explanation on why or why not.

Thanks.

Comment: Do note that your code is wrong.  A RECT is not compatible with Rectangle.  DestroyStructure *can* be required but in only very select corner cases.  It is necessary when it contains COM types, BSTR or interface pointers.  Not the case here.

Comment: I know the code is wrong, it's just something I grabbed of the web for example purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, then how can you be sure that you got the correct answer?  DestroyStructure can be necessary in some cases.

Comment: Well, I'm not creating any new structures. Actually I'm listening to the device change event (usb) and marshalling from the pointer into a DevBroadcastDeviceinterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything more than you have here. The unmanaged memory is owned by the system. It allocated it, and it will dispose of it.

You did not allocate any unmanaged memory. You simply copied the contents of the unmanaged struct that you were passed into a new managed struct. The .net GC will take take of the lifetime of that managed object.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if you didn't allocate it (`AllocHGlobal` in the case of `Marshal`), you should't need to deallocate it.